# angular listing not working when i compare two fields?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```
<div  ng-controller="SamsungServicesCtrl">
     <ion-content> 
           <li class="item item-checkbox"  ng-repeat="item in items" >
             <img src="{{item.icon}}"  style="float:left;height:30px;width:30px;padding-right:5px;" > 
             <label  class="checkbox checkbox-energized"  >
               <input type="checkbox"  style="float:right;"   ng-model="item.selected"  >
             </label>
             {{item.name}}
              <p style="font-size:10px;  padding-left:0px;">  {{item.subname}}</p>
           </li>
           <div class="padding">
            <button class="button button-full button-energized"  value="submit" ng-click="check()">Apply
            </button>
           </div>

    </ion-content>
</div>
<script>
.controller('SamsungServicesCtrl', function ($scope,$filter,$location) {
       var service = ["Regular Service", "Settings Faults", "Software Faults", "Hardware Faults"];
       var services = ["General services", "If a phone doesn’t switch-on, it is called a dead phone, SIM card does not get detected", "Hardware Faults"];
       var icons = ["images/arrow.svg","images/arrow.svg","images/arrow.svg"];
         $scope.items= [] ;
            for(var I=0;I<service.length;I++)
                {
                    var modal = {
                        name:service[I],
                        subname:services[I],
                        icon:icons[I],
                        selected:false
                      }; 

                    $scope.items.push(modal);        
                }
                scope.check = function()
                {
                      var checkedItems = [];
                       for(var I=0;I<$scope.items.length;I++){
                          if($scope.items[I].selected){
                             checkedItems.push($scope.items[I].name);
                             }
                            }


        //I have checked Regular Service, Settings Faults
        $location.path('listing').search({model: 'samsung', items:checkedItems});
                 }

    })  
</script>
```

I have given my services page html and controller. In this page contains list of services one more thing this is my first page here user need to select any one of this services. After user click apply button I am redirecting to listing page with selected services: store type(nokia,samsung)( $location.path('listing').search({model: 'samsung', items:checkedItems})). Here user only selected services but I appended model name as Samsung.

```
<div class="bar bar-header item-input-inset">
    <label class="item-input-wrapper" >
         <I class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></I>
         <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="query" >
    </label>
</div>
<div class="list card"  data-ng-repeat="dealer in dealers |  filter:query ">
    <div class="item item-thumbnail-left item-icon-right" href="#">
         <h2>{{dealer.Store_Name}}</h2> 
         <p>{{dealer.S_Address.area}} {{dealer.S_Address.city}}</p> 
         <p>{{dealer.S_Services}}</p>
    </div>   
</div>

listing page
<script>
listing controller
.controller('ListingCtrl', [
'$scope', '$http', '$location', '$window', '$filter','$ionicPopover','$ionicLoading',
function($scope, $http, $location, $window, $filter, $ionicPopover, $ionicLoading) {
$scope.dealers = [{
        S_Date_add: "2015-07-24T13:45:23.927Z",
        S_Email_id: "aditiya@gmail.com",
        S_Store: "samsung",
        Store_Name: "Adtiya Samsung Store",
        S_Services: "Regular Service,Software Faults,Hardware Faults,Interior faults",
        Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of samsung mobiles",
        Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of samsung mobiles",
    }, {
        S_Date_add: "2015-07-24T13:45:23.927Z",
        S_Email_id: "rajs@gmail.com",
        S_Store: "nokia",
        Store_Name: "sri shakthi mobile service",
        S_Services: "Settings Faults,Regular Service,Hardware Faults",
        Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia mobiles",
        Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia mobiles",
    }, {
        S_Date_add: "2015-07-24T13:45:23.927Z",
        S_Email_id: "sprtive23@gmail.com",
        S_Store: "nokia,samsung",
        Store_Name: "sun mobile service center",
        S_Services: "overall faults,Regular Service,",
        Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia,samsung mobiles",
        Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia,samsung mobiles"
    }, {
        S_Date_add: "2015-07-24T13:45:23.927Z",
        S_Email_id: "siva@gmail.com",
        S_Store: "nokia,samsung",
        Store_Name: "mobile service center",
        S_Services: "overall faults,mobile faults",
        Store_long_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia,samsung mobiles",
        Store_short_description: "Undertake all kind of nokia,samsung mobiles"}
    ]


      var model = $location.search().model;
      var items = $location.search().items;
      console.log(filter);
      //filter value iam getting in console samsung 
      console.log(items);
     //items value getting in console  Regular Service,Hardware Faults
     //I have done some logic here to check 
            $scope.dealers=[];
            for(var I=0;I<data.length;I++){
                var temp=data[I].S_Store.split(',');
                 var temp1=data[I].S_Services.split(',');
                for(var j=0;j<temp.length:j++){

                     for(var k=0;j<temp1.length:k++)
                     {
                     if(temp[j]===model ||temp1 === items)
                       $scope.dealers.push(data[I]);
                     }

                    }
                }


}])
</script>
```

Above code listing page html and controller. In this page I need to display stores based on user selection. In the listing page I am getting model value and items value.

List of Stores Should Be:

1. model should match with S_Store
2. items should match with S_Services

   I did logic but its not working

Example condtion
if user coming from samsung page so I have appended model values as samsung
and user selected Regular Service ,Hardware Faults.here I am redirecting like this
$location.path('listing').search({model: 'samsung', items:'Regular Service, Hardware Faults'});
so selected values I checked in console it's coming
but I need to show matched store list 
1. Adtiya Samsung Store
2. sri shakthi mobile service
3. sun mobile service center

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a few things that come to mind in reading through each of those. In your first code block, you are iterating through the `service` array and it's got four elements, though both the `icons` and `services` arrays only have three, so that's going to show unexpected information.

In the second segment, you're iterating through a `data` variable that hasn't yet been defined. Also, just prior to that, you're re-initializing the $scope.dealers object to an empty array and clearing out the information you previously set on the page, so that's probably not expected.

See if resolving those two issues yields what you're looking for there.

Edit: Here's some code that might help out in the second half in response to your comment.

```
var result = [];
for(var a = 0; a < $scope.dealers.length; a++) {
    var storeSpl = $scope.dealers[a].S_Store.split(',');
    //Iterate through the store for matches
    for(var b = 0; b < storeSpl.length; b++) {
        if (storeSpl[b] === model)
            result.push(storeSpl[b]);
    }

    var servicesSpl = $scope.dealers[a].S_Services.split(',');
    var itemsSpl = items.split(','); //I'm assuming this is serialized as an array - I haven't personally used $location before
    //Iterate through the services for matches
    for(var b = 0; b < servicesSpl.length; b++) {
        for(var c = 0; c < itemsSpl.length; c++) {
            if(servicesSpl[b] === itemsSpl[c]) 
                result.push(servicesSpl[b]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i know my logic is wrong.in dealers  i need to check where samsung(S_Store),Regular Service,Hardware Faults (S_Services matched.i need to display based on matched condtion

Comment: My point is that you're overwriting the very array that I assume you're trying to read from in that second part, so you won't have any data to iterate through. Read my updated answer.

Comment: what should i do now?help me out to move forward

Comment: Again, please read the example I provided you in my answer. I can't help you unless I know where you're having difficulty with this.

Comment: $scope.dealers=[];
            for(var I=0;I<data.length;I++){
                var temp=data[I].S_Store.split(',');
                 var temp1=data[I].S_Services.split(',');
                for(var j=0;j<temp.length:j++){

                     for(var k=0;j<temp1.length:k++)
                     {
                     if(temp[j]===model ||temp1 === items)
                       $scope.dealers.push(data[I]);
                     }

                    }
                }this part not working

Comment: Again, it won't work at all because data isn't defined in that scope. There's simply nothing to iterate through.